# Превышенный лимит проверок влияет на разные типы проверок?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, очередь-проверок

Первый раз превысил лимит проверок по сообщениям низкого качества.
Сейчас захожу на проверку запоздалых ответов:
[Перед вами ответ на старый вопрос, опубликованный новым участником](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/120693)
Хочу "осудить" данный ответ, выбрать из списка причину как обычно. Но сервис SO мне предлагает только два варианта:

1. Действия не требуются
2. Пропустить

Это связано с тем, что по другому типу проверок я исчерпал лимит?

Comment: Обычно да. Например, если голоса на закрытие исчерпаны, то закрыть вопрос через список проверки в другой очереди (например, низкого качества) так же не получится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, дело именно в том, что обойму удалений вы полностью расстреляли. В будущем в подобной ситуации вы можете открыть ответ в отдельной странице и нажать, например,

- > "тревога"

  - > "не является ответом" (если это другой вопрос, комментарий или ссылка) или
  - > "необходимо удалить из-за проблем с качеством" (если это вообще что-то невменяемое).

После этого ответ попадёт в соответствующую очередь проверок (если ещё в ней не был). Например, этот ответ [был удалён](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/120695) из очереди "низкого качества".